# Unable to change react input field state , Always Ends up with the initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, forms

This is Edit profile feature i am trying to build.first i get the user details and fill up the fields by assigning them to a state

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
if (localStorage.getItem('userInfo') === null) {
    navigate('/login')
}
else{
userInfo=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
setName(userInfo.name)
}
},)
```

until now everything is fine i can see the name in input field default value

```
 <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId='name'>
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='name'
            placeholder='Enter name'
            defaultValue={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
```

when i submit the form i am still sending the initial value to the server not the edited value.

Comment: Could you show form submit function?

Comment: const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
          setMessage('Passwords do not match')
         } else {
         const formData={name}
          updateResponse=await updateUser(formData);
            console.log(updateResponse)
             }
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to call the useEffect only on the component first render by adding [] at the dependency array of the useEffect

Answer (score 1):

You need to add function to onChange Param. I added the code example.

```
export default function App() {
      const [name, setName] = useState(""); // useState hook

  // handle change event
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    setName(e.target.value); // set name to e.target.value (event)
  };

  // render
  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Control
            defaultValue={name}
            type="name"
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `You need to add function to onChange Param`?

Comment: It would be better if you add the function than adding the useState variable directly. And one more thing, don't forget to prevent the default action and set the value. It's very important.

Comment: Did you see @Tarmah's answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `defaultValue` with `value`

and use the useEffect in this way [React useState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3C0X.png)

Comment: if i replace with value i can't even edit the input field

Comment: Is react throwing any errors? Have you checked the console?

Comment: nope , but i now know why it's happening . every time i change input filed , the state changes and the component re renders , obviously the useEffect runs again and sets the value to initial value

Comment: i am thinking to use useRef now instead of usestate